# is this python benchmark useful?

Tags: python

I recently tried to run an Project Euler problem in python. It was my belief that it would do something like 100^5 steps.

After seeing that my solution wat taking too long (it is supposed to run in under a minute) I asked myself if *any* python program that ran this many steps would be viable (under a minute)

so, I designed a foolish little test

```
def fun():
  l=range(1,100)
  for x in l:
     for y in l:
        for k in l:
           for n in l:
               for h in l:
                  s=1

>>> t = timeit.Timer('demorado.fun()','import demorado')
>>> t.timeit(1)
1202.484529018402
>>>
```

does is make sense ? Does it prove that any program with this many steps (in this case, I guess there are 2*(100^5)) always demands some 20 minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python it's probably a good estimate.  Using numpy or C++ extensions might speed up your Project Euler code, but remember all problems on Project Euler are designed to be solvable in <1 min.  It's very unlikely you are required to run 100^5 operations in order to arrive at the correct solution.  I'd try to approach the problem from a different angle if I were you.

Comment: In C, it ran just under a minute.

Then, looking at the answers, I saw a small modification that seems to make things aprox 100x faster. I'll look further into it. Thanks, though

Answer (score 2):

Project Euler problems are not supposed to run in under a minute because your programming language is *fast* enough, but because there exists a solution that's *cleverer* than just brute force.

But in your case, yes, you'll get a function that loops `99^5` times (not `100^5` because `range(1,100)` is `1, 2, ..., 99`)...

Answer (score 2):

It is a reasonable assumption, though I am not sure it is doing what you want. In real life this might be closer:

```
for i in xrange(100 ** 5): pass
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does it prove that any program with this many steps always demands some 20 minutes ?

Depends on your definition of "step". Here is code that requires about 99^5 floating point operations, but runs in about 1 second:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(shape=(1681, 1681), dtype=np.float32) # 1681 x 1681 matrix
b = np.dot(a, a) # matrix product
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pass` instead of `s=1` in the inner loop.

Also, use `numpy.nditer` with "external_loop" option, or write the loops in Cython if loops turn out to be your bottleneck.